# error tells me that property EmployeeNumber is not queryable; documentation says the opposite

Tags: sql, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Using the Intuit Partner Platform, when I try to query QuickBooks for an employee using this query,

```
select * from Employee where EmployeeNumber = '1'
```

it complains:

```
ERROR CODE:4001
ERROR MESSAGE:Invalid query
ERROR DETAIL:QueryValidationError: property 'EmployeeNumber' is not queryable
```

[But the documentation says that EmployeeNumber is both "Filterable" and "Sortable".](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/employee#Employee_Attributes)

So, maybe I just can't query employees at all. Nope. That's not it. The following query ran just fine:

```
select * from Employee where Id = '1'
```

So, what's up? Why can't I filter on EmployeeNumber?

Comment: sounds like a question for Intuit.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Intuit about this - it's definitely a bug with their service or docs.

Comment: Intuit's response: Hello Keith,   

This is with the engineering team. They will confirm if it's a docs bug or services bug.   

Sincerely,

Nimisha Shrivastava 
Intuit

Comment: Could you link to your bug report?

Comment: Intuit doesn't have a public bug tracker so there's no way to link to it - they just sent this back to me: RE: Case 00008271:  Employee object v3 bug [ ref:_00DG0COk8._500G0JMLtp:ref ]   Hi Keith,

The engineering team will try to fix this bug in the next release.
Closing this ticket. You can respond back to reopen this, if you need to check the status.

Thanks,
Nimisha

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a doc issue. Also you should be clear that the EmployeeNumber is NOT the same as Id. 
The id is a unique system generated sequence while the EmployeeNumber in the API is actually the "Employee Id" if look at the employee details in the Employee tab in QBO. You can give multiple employees the same EmployeeNumber.

Comment: Yes. I am quite aware of the difference. That's why I have this problem. If Id and EmployeeNumber were the same thing, I would just query on one and not the other. But I need to search specifically by EmployeeNumber, as I'm using that field to reference an entity in a database.